# Colored build output in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, colors

I am using a Visual Studio project with custom build script/batch file (ala make, ant, etc.).

When the build is run from the command line we have placed colored highlighting on various output lines.

However, when built via Visual Studio (2005 in my case) the output window does not show the color anymore.

Is this possible? I am quite happy to put specific code into the build script if required.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to go with the pro version of the VSCommands plug-in, there is a free one called VSColorOutput, which does just that. I've worked with it a bit, does what it says.

See http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/12/vscoloroutput-visual-studio-output.html or look it up in the extension gallery.

Comment: Important information: I have VS2010, not sure if it works with older versions as well.

Comment: This, is really cool ! Thanks a lot, and one upvote for you !

Comment: You're welcome. Apparently, the majority of .NET people are used to pay for small extensions such as VSCommands, I see no other reason why VSColorOutput is not more widespread :-)

Comment: Well I can see another reason : VSCommands is way more advertised. When I looked for coloured build input under VS, I found VSCommands in less than 5 minutes, while I had to do a bit of research to find VSColorOutput. I prefer VSColorOutput though, not only because it's free but because it just does what it says :)

Comment: The current Visual Studio Gallery URL is https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496

Comment: VSColorOutput has a bug: you can change the default color palette. Thus you cannot have a black forecolor.

Answer (score 10):

The [VSCommands](http://vscommands.com/) plug-in for Visual Studio 2010 adds colour formatting to the output window so errors are red. I'm not sure how they are doing it but it might give you a starting point.

Comment: hmm interesting..  i wonder if its only a vs2010 thing..  thanks

Comment: As I know only Pro version supports it. It is blocked in Free version however :(

Comment: See my answer below for a free alternative

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't with your build scripts, but with Visual Studio not supporting [ANSI control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to change the color.